# Void user check RadioButton without disabling it

Tags: vb.net, winforms, radio-button

I have four RadioButtons inside a GroupBox and I need to forbid user to change it status but without disabling the control because I need that they look NOT disabled(grayed).
I'm controlling them from code.
I tried to change AutoClick to false but I get more than one RadioButton checked when I change them by code.

Of course I can change all the RadioButtons status every time but that looks a bit messy.

Comment: Why would you change a paradigm that is well understood by pretty much every computer user and make a UI behave unintuitively?

Comment: Add JQuery on change event and return false will solve your problem.

Comment: Because I have two Tab Controls, one to program the configuration of a device connected to USB port and another to read it current configuration. So the user see almost the same controls and don't loses time looking for a specific configuration.

Comment: @TonyDong This is a WinForm on VB.NET, a far I know I can't use Javascript in VB.NET 2010

Comment: @E_Blue You could if add web browser for it. See this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240746/executing-javascript-code-from-c-sharp-winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inherited class for this.

Mark IsReadOnly to true to disable the click.

```
Class ReadOnlyRadioButton
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton

    Private mRo as Boolean

    Public Property IsReadOnly As Boolean
        Get
            Return mRo 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value as String)
            mRo = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If Not Me.IsReadOnly Then
            MyBase.OnClick(e)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```